# Options for prepaid cell service in Toronto

Tags: budget, cellphones, toronto

I'm visiting Toronto tomorrow and will be there for about two weeks.  I have a 2G unlocked phone that I originally purchased from Fido, so I would only need a SIM card. I'm thinking about getting a prepaid one, but I'm not sure if I can get it for such a short-term use.

What are my options of getting a SIM card?  And is it possible to do this directly at Toronto's Pearson airport?

Comment: I should've looked carefully. Thanks for pointing me to a duplicate question.